# Inconsistent loading of keras backend between theano and tensorflow

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, theano, keras

My `keras.json` has backend specified to be `tensorflow` and if I open Spyder and Jupyter IDE then `tensorflow` is used as a backend.

Strangely if I open `python` or `ipython` shell within my WinPython installation, the backend defaults into `theano`. Has anyone seen this behaviour before and if so what was the solution?

I have tried playing with environment variables to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same issue. Some how after I installed shell kernel Ipython/Jupyter is pointing properly to tensor flow

```
import os

os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='tensorflow'
import keras
keras.backend.backend()
```

Comment: Is your installation a WinPython one though?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like existing notebooks still say Theano. But If I create new one and enter the following then I get proper result as tensorflow
    import os

```
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='tensorflow'
import keras
keras.backend.backend()
```

Using TensorFlow backend.
Out[1]:
'tensorflow'
In [ ]: